# Computing an explicit solution to an integral equation via the Neumann Series.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, integration, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am hoping that someone can provide guidance for solving the integral equation
$$u=f+\lambda Au$$
where $1/\lambda\notin\sigma(A)$, $f\in L^2[0,2\pi]$, and $A:L^2[0,2\pi]\to L^2[0,2\pi]$ is defined via
$$Au(x)=\int_0 ^{2\pi}\cos(x+t)u(t)dt.$$
In particular, I would like to write the solution in the form
$$u(x)=\varphi(x)+\int_0 ^{2\pi}\Delta(\lambda,x,t)\varphi(t)dt.$$
Some of my thoughts towards a solution have been to use the Neumann series so that 
$$u(x)=\sum_{n=0} ^\infty\lambda ^nu_n(x)$$
where 
$$
    \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       u_0(x)=f(x)\\
      u_{n+1}(x)=\int_0 ^{2\pi}\cos(x+t)u_n(t)dt
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
but after pages of calculations to put it into the form I seek, I am not sure if this is the way to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral kernel is actually separable, since $\cos(x+t)=\cos(x)\cos(t)-\sin(x)\sin(t)$.  This should make the problem significantly easier to handle, i.e. you can solve it explicitly without the Neumann series.

Comment: How so? I tried using the identity before, but I must confess to me it seems to complicate the situation more as now we have to solve $$u(x)=f(x)+\lambda \cos x\int_0 ^{2\pi}\cos t u(t)dt-\lambda \sin x\int_0 ^{2\pi}\sin t u(t)dt$$

Comment: Also, another thought I had was to try to turn this into an ode, but we only have $u\in L^2$, so that we don't know if it is differentiable.

Comment: Ok, I looked in my text book the conveniently had a section on separable kernels, so I got it now. Thank you for leading me in the right direction!